# SMTP - 503 Bad sequence of commands when using nim's std/smtp

Tags: email, ssl, smtp, nim-lang, starttls

I am building a web application in the nim programming language and recently wanted to start implementing features regarding sending mails.

Nim has a [library `std/smtp`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/smtp.html) for this that comes with some pretty simple examples for using both `starttls` and `ssl`.

For that purpose I created a dummy mail address on a [local mail service provider](https://hilfe.web.de/pop-imap/pop3/serverdaten.html) to play around a bit and can't get it to work, despite following the examples as closely as I could.

Here the code I used:

```
import std/[smtp]

let smtpServerName = "smtp.web.de"
let startTlsportNumber = 587
let un = "dummymail" # replace with actual username
let pw = "dummypw" # replace with actual pw
let target = "bla@mailinator.com"

#StartTLS code block - Have either this or the SSL code block commented in, not both
let smtpConn = newSmtp(debug=true)
smtpConn.connect(smtpServerName, Port startTlsportNumber)
smtpConn.startTls()


#SSL code block - Have either this or the startTLS code block commented in, not both
# let sslPortNumber = 465
# let smtpConn = newSmtp(useSsl = true, debug=true)
# smtpConn.connect(smtpServerName, Port sslPortNumber)


var msg = createMessage(mSubject = "Hello from Nim's SMTP",
                        mBody = "Hello!.\n Is this awesome or what?",
                        mTo = @[target])
smtpConn.auth(un, pw)
smtpConn.sendmail(un, @[target], $msg)
```

With startTLS this causes a runtime error as the server sends back a 503 response on `smtpConn.startTls`:

```
S:220 web.de (mrweb105) Nemesis ESMTP Service ready
C:HELO smtp.web.de

S:250 web.de Hello smtp.web.de [46.183.103.17]
C:STARTTLS

S:503 Bad sequence of commands
C:QUIT
/home/philipp/dev/playground/src/playground.nim(11) playground
/usr/lib/nim/pure/smtp.nim(246) startTls
/usr/lib/nim/pure/smtp.nim(226) checkReply
/usr/lib/nim/pure/smtp.nim(110) quitExcpt
Error: unhandled exception: Expected 220 reply, got: 503 Bad sequence of commands [ReplyError]
```

With SSL this causes a runtime error as the server sends back a 503 response on `smtpConn.connect`:

```
S:220 web.de (mrweb005) Nemesis ESMTP Service ready
C:HELO smtp.web.de

S:503 Bad sequence of commands
C:QUIT
/home/philipp/dev/playground/src/playground.nim(15) playground
/usr/lib/nim/pure/smtp.nim(240) connect
/usr/lib/nim/pure/smtp.nim(231) helo
/usr/lib/nim/pure/smtp.nim(226) checkReply
/usr/lib/nim/pure/smtp.nim(110) quitExcpt
Error: unhandled exception: Expected 250 reply, got: 503 Bad sequence of commands [ReplyError]
```

I've triple checked the ports, the service provider states explicitly that 587 is the port for startTls and 465 for SSL. I compile on Arch Linux with `-d:ssl` in both cases, so that shouldn't be an issue either.

Trying the same with google-mail it all worked out, but I am slightly annoyed that this didn't work with my original mail provider.

Googling the error for a bit and looking at other questions of other programming languages, the error seems to be related to authentication? Which is weird, because I thought authentication starts after I made the connection secure with startTls. This looks to me like I'm using the std/smtp library wrong, but I don't quite see where. Does anyone here see the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The server doesn't like the HELO that std/smtp uses, it needs EHLO:

```
$ telnet smtp.web.de 587
[ ... ]
220 web.de (mrweb105) Nemesis ESMTP Service ready
HELO smtp.web.de
250 web.de Hello smtp.web.de [92.191.80.254]
STARTTLS
503 Bad sequence of commands

$ telnet smtp.web.de 587
[ ... ]
220 web.de (mrweb006) Nemesis ESMTP Service ready
EHLO smtp.web.de
250-web.de Hello smtp.web.de [92.191.80.254]
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE 141557760
250 STARTTLS
STARTTLS
220 OK
```

So you can get the Nim dev version with [this patch](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/pull/19077), or copy-paste the patch code into your program while it doesn't reach the stable:

```
import std / [net, strutils, asyncnet, asyncdispatch]


proc recvEhlo(smtp: Smtp | AsyncSmtp): Future[bool] {.multisync.} =
  ## Skips "250-" lines, read until "250 " found.
  ## Return `true` if server supports `EHLO`, false otherwise.
  while true:
    var line = await smtp.sock.recvLine()
    echo("S:" & line) # Comment out this if you aren't debugging
    if line.startsWith("250-"): continue
    elif line.startsWith("250 "): return true # last line
    else: return false

proc ehlo*(smtp: Smtp | AsyncSmtp): Future[bool] {.multisync.} =
  # Sends the EHLO request
  await smtp.debugSend("EHLO " & smtp.address & "\c\L")
  return await smtp.recvEhlo()

proc connect*(smtp: Smtp | AsyncSmtp, address: string, port: Port) {.multisync.} =
  smtp.address = address
  await smtp.sock.connect(address, port)
  await smtp.checkReply("220")
  let speaksEsmtp = await smtp.ehlo()
  if speaksEsmtp:
    await smtp.debugSend("STARTTLS\c\L")
    await smtp.checkReply("220")

let smtpConn = newSmtp(debug=true)
smtpConn.connect("smtp.web.de", Port 587)
```

Notice that you need to avoid the call to `startTls` because the unpatched version does a `HELO` that would raise another 503, so we send the `STARTTLS` at the end of our modified `connect`.

I've noticed that you need to modify your local `smtp.nim` file to make `sock` field for `SmtpBase` object public for this to work. The file is at `nim-1.6.6/lib/pure/smtp.nim` and you need to change:

```
62    sock: SocketType
```

to

```
62    sock*: SocketType
```

So it might be better to just patch the whole `smtp.nim` local file with the code linked above.